# Wikipedia: pages across multiple languages

Tags: java, nlp, wikipedia, information-retrieval

I want to use wikipedia dump for my project. The below information is required for my project.

1. For an wikipedia entry, I want to know which other language contain the page?
2. I want an downloadable data in csv or other common format.

Is there a way to get this data?

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikimedia foundation provides XML dumps of all of its projects, including the English language Wikipedia.

Parsing an English-language wiki article for inter-language links is fairly easy: the syntax for such links are `[[language_code:Name of other language Wikipedia article]]`, where language_code is usually a two or three letter code (such as `tlh` for Klingon), based on an  ISO standard except for a few exceptions, such as `simple` for Simple English.

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia provides dumps of Wikipedia in different formats at [download.wikimedia.org](http://download.wikimedia.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question even if it's old because things have changed: now there's [Wikidata](http://wikidata.org/).

All the *interlinks* have been eliminated from Wikipedia articles, and now Wikidata hosts them all: you can check an Item (for example, [Q42](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42) "Douglas Adams") and the "Wikipedia pages linked to this item" section will provide you with the *sitelinks* to all different Wikipedias.

Here you can find [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php), or you can use the [Special:Export](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:Export) page to retrieve the article(s) in XML.